# how to create a Spring data jpa repository with a clause ON

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, repository

Suppose we have two classes A and B : 
Class A :

```
public class A {private Long id;}
```

Class B :

```
public class B {private Long id; private String name ; private Boolean isDeleted = false; }
```

Is there a way to have results of Join query with some other conditions besides the condition ON
I tried this but I doesn't work , the compiler doesn't recognize clause ON `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token`  :

```
 @Query( "SELECT new com.demo.DTO.resultsDTO(a.id) FROM A ate , B a  ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.isDeleted = false AND b.name = ?1  ")
```

I tried also to include the a.id = b.id in the clause WHERE, but it doesn't return results.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is off, and is mixing the old-school implicit join syntax with the modern (preferred) join syntax.  Here is the version you should be using:

```
SELECT new com.demo.DTO.resultsDTO(a.id)
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
    b.isDeleted = false AND
    b.name = ?1;
```

Your updated Java code:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.demo.DTO.resultsDTO(a.id) FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.isDeleted = false AND b.name = ?1")
```